# Is there a website where you can enter a list of your skills and find out what types of jobs you are qualified for?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm envisioning a website where you type in a list of your skills and get back a list of job alternatives or near-alternatives; alternatives that aren't so obvious.  Alternatives that may require just a little more training.

I'm looking to expand my horizons beyond what I have already done and a site like that would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.behance.net/. It combines the idea of an easy to maintain online portfolio with job hunting.

If you are looking to expand even further you should look into grabbing some work from http://www.elance.com/. Most of the calls for work on elance are short term projects that will help you get your feet wet in the parts of design you haven't got to experience yet.

Best of luck to you!

Comment: Thank you! Though I don't want to mark this question as answered just yet, I'd like to see some more suggestions.